# Map reduce with nested values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I've got a nested hourly data structure of counters http://pastebin.com/KgbsYBW7. The count of nested levels is constant, but values can be different or similar. But if I run map function:

```
 function () { emit(this.date, this.data); }
```

Then not all entries for date value reduced. 
If I use:

```
 function () { emit(this.hour, this.data); }
```

Then all rows reduced.
I know, that map reduce working with similar data, but how to aggregate my entries by "date"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For correct results, command **mapReduce** should be executed with **sort** param, because mapped values may sent to reduce function separated:

**Before sorting**

```
{ ISODate("2015-12-17T00:00:00Z") } => [ { data : {}}, { data : {}}]
{ ISODate("2015-12-18T00:00:00Z") } => [ { data : {}}}]
{ ISODate("2015-12-17T00:00:00Z") } => [ { data : {}}, { data : {}}, { data : {}}]
{ ISODate("2015-12-19T00:00:00Z") } => [ { data : {}}]
```

**With sorting**  {sort : { hour : 1}}

```
{ ISODate("2015-12-17T00:00:00Z") } => [ { data : {}}, { data : {}},{ data : {}}, { data : {}}, { data : {}}]
{ ISODate("2015-12-18T00:00:00Z") } => [ { data : {}}}]
{ ISODate("2015-12-19T00:00:00Z") } => [ { data : {}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce your data by single day you need to set the same time for this day.

You can do it like this:

```
function () {
    var date = new Date(this.date.getFullYear(), this.date.getMonth(), this.date.getDate());
    emit(date, this.data);
}
```

Comment: I need to aggregate for data for any range by date.

Comment: So you have date_from, date_to and want to see aggregated result foreach day in date range [date_from, date_to]. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, I using map reduce query  with $gte / $lte with date range